# Is "foursome" appropriate?

Tags: word-choice

Does the suffix "some", when it comes after a number, conjure up some kind of an orgy?

Here is an example:

> Have you heard that Jim and Tina made up a foursome with Jean and Bruce?

would you ever ask such a question from someone you barely know (considering that you just *assume* he or she has some idea of what you're talking about)? In other words, is the risk of misinterpretation subtle enough for you to take?

Here I'm not taking into account those who have a so-called "dirty mind" and tend to interpret everything their own way. Instead, I'm interested to know how the **majority** of English-speaking people (especially those of the United States) would interpret that.

Comment: I think this is a completely pointless question. Context is everything, and it really makes no sense to present us with an effectively "context-free" utterance simply in order to ask how many people see sexual overtones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Hello FumbleFingers, would you like to have a foursome with me and two other users of StackExchange?" This is a real situation and I didn't provide any broad "context" because I assumed that you know I'm talking about forming a study group (while you weren't though). Now if you got slightly offended, this proves that there is a default interpretation for such a sentence, the one I would try to avoid by providing more context.

Comment: I'm certainly not "offended". If you stop to think about it, I'm sure you'll realise that both sexes often fantasise about *threesomes* with two others of the ***opposite*** sex, even though in practice I believe only a minority actually have the experience. But PC or no, most people are quite naturally homophobic at the visceral/physical level, so sexual fantasies (and indeed, actual experiences) involving a *foursome* are far less common. But frankly, I don't see that any of this is On Topic for discussion on ELU.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't even thinking about the difference between threesome and foursome because I just wanted to provide and example. Now I can conclude that without giving more context, my sentence would be either fine (when people know what I'm talking about) or it would be nonsense (when they don't have a clue) and either way I won't offend them unintentionally.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't offend *me*, but the mere fact that you were motivated to ask here suggests that *you* at least see ***inherent*** sexual connotations in "threesome". Incidentally, naming two M/F pairs in your example, and the "gossipy" associations of *have you heard...* would both steer one towards a smutty/sexual meaning - but as I said before, most people don't even *fantasise* about sexual foursomes, so you'd probably need to be even more explicit to make them think along those lines.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I was suspicious about inherent sexual connotations in "threesome". So if my sentence was "Have you heard that Tina made up a threesome with Jim and Bruce?" then would it be explicit enough for most people to be considered an innuendo when they are not provided with an explanation? (because most people, according to you, fantasize about that)

Comment: @ Nate: I think you're preoccupied with the idea that short utterances have disembodied/contextless meanings, when mostly they don't. When we discuss what some phrase *means* on ELU, we're often just guessing, because there's insufficient context. In the *real* world, every utterance is normally part of a longer conversation, with far more verbal *and* "external" context. Children may notice and snigger at "accidental" innuendoes, but in my experience adults are normally interested in the *intended* meaning, and they simply don't notice potential "contrived" interpretations.

Comment: Many words can prompt either juvenile sniggering, or people to blush at an innuendo; I'd count _threesome_ among the words with a relatively high probability of doing that. Obviously, the less context provided, the more likely it might evoke the innuendo. Despite FF's last remark, these things do occur now and then. I had a friend once tell another couple "Wanna check out the bed?" and then blushed after he said it (he wanted to show them new  furniture). I think this is a fair question, but, by deliberately providing so little context, you made it hard to see what you were driving at.

Comment: I feel it's a valid question for "ELL". Here we expect lot of non-native English speakers and, as compared to native speakers, they may/may not be aware of the word "some" used after numbers as in the case of "threesome" and "foursome". By my experience, "threesome" definitely has sexual innuendos while "foursome" could remind someone of a threesome. Problem with this question could be its title which could be generalized more by not being specifically only about "Foursome".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the word would be inherently interpreted with sexual connotations, but as is often the case, context is all important.

For example, your sentence is lacking context and begins with "Have you heard...?" which suggests some element of gossip. However, if you added context to that, such as:

> Do you know who Jim and Tina are playing golf with?
>
> Yeah, they've made a foursome with Jim and Tina.

The issue with your question is that, in isolation, the lack of context seems *deliberate* - as there's no indication for what purpose they've formed a foursome - and that's where the potential for innuendo appears.

Of course, people will also take cues from your tone and body language, so your meaning should be conveyed correctly, given that you provide sufficient context.

Just to make clear, I'm a British English speaker (and live in that region), but I think it's important to provide a global view. I'm not personally sure that the Americans would see matters any differently, but I do find issues of this nature fascinating.

Comment: I would like to note as an American, I have never heard the term foursome used in any other than one of two contexts: 1) sports (usually golf, but I think I've heard it with tennis too), 2) sex. I will note that '-some' isn't the potentially sexual part, as with 'gruesome twosome'. Threesome: wink wink, nudge nudge. Foursome: maybe. Twosome, fivesome, seventysome...I'd just assume it was a group of that size, unless I was being winked at and nudged. Otherwise I entirely agree with your answer, +1

Comment: " Innuendo " my word for the day!

Answer (score 6):

How **any** word or sentence is understood depends on context.

Sentences like “Jim and Tina made up a foursome with Jean and Bruce” only occur by themselves like this in grammar books, where they illustrate some particular point. In real life they occur inside some larger context—a conversation, or a letter, or a history, or whatever.

This sentence might occur in the context of activity at a country club, where it would most likely refer to  groupings in tennis or golf or bridge. It might occur in the context of a grad-school seminar, where it would most likely have to do people working together on a presentation. Or it might occur in the context of gossip about the sexual behavior of friends or business colleagues, where it would most likely have the piquant implication you suggest.

Context, context, context.

Answer (score 0):

"Foursome" can be appropriate in non-sexual contexts. For instance, a foursome at bridge. Or a foursome at doubles (or mixed doubles) tennis.

Although I once wrote a short story in which two couples traded spouses after playing mixed doubles tennis.

Comment: Tom, interesting! But, how many copies, if any, had been sold?

Comment: Unless the two couples were in the same room, though, that would only make _one_ foursome – the one on the tennis courts. You could say there were _two_ instances of "swinging" though: starting with the swinging of rackets on the tennis court...

Comment: What is "a foursome at bridge"? Can't it have more than one interpretation?!

Comment: @Nate: Bridge is a card game played with four people at a table, generally referred to as South (declarer), West (leader), North (dummy), and East (responder).